# How do you change multiple CSS as the same time with different clicks?

Tags: javascript, html, css

As you can see when you click the first amazon icon the boxes on the button are selected. How do I highlight a box that isn't highlighted at the same time. So for example if you click the first button 1,3, and 5 are selected. How would i keep those highlighted and then click the second amazon and highlight/or change the CSS of box number 2 so that 1,2,3 and 5 are changed to orange?

```js
    $("input[type=image]").on ("click", function() {
    $("p.the-text").removeClass("colorized");
    var cat = $(this).attr("data-cat");
    $("p.the-text." + cat).addClass("colorized");
    })
```

```css
    p.the-text, p.the-text1, p.the-text2, p.the-text3, p.the-text4, p.the-text5,p.the-text6, p.the-text7, p.the-text8, p.the-text9, p.the-text10, p.the-text11, p.the-text12, p.the-text13, p.the-text14, p.the-text15, p.the-text16,p.the-text17, p.the-text18, p.the-text19  {border-color: #CACACA;padding:10px;color:#CACACA;font-weight:bold;background-color:white;font-family:"ff-din-web-condensed", sans-serif;border-style: solid;border-width: 1px;}

    p.the-text.colorized, p.the-text2.colorzied, p.the-text3.colorzied, p.the-text4.colorzied, p.the-text5.colorzied, p.the-text6.colorzied, p.the-text7.colorzied, p.the-text8.colorzied, p.the-text9.colorzied, p.the-text10.colorzied, p.the-text11.colorzied, p.the-text12.colorzied, p.the-text13.colorzied, p.the-text14.colorzied, p.the-text15.colorzied, p.the-text16.colorzied, p.the-text17.colorzied, p.the-text18.colorzied, p.the-text19.colorzied {color: white;background-color:orange;border-color:orange;font-family:"ff-din-web-condensed", sans-serif;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <input type="image" data-cat="cat1" id="theButton0" src="https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/4039958/ama-orange.0.png" style="height:50px" />

    <input type="image" data-cat="cat2" id="theButton1" src="https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/4039958/ama-orange.0.png" style="height:50px" />

    <input type="image" data-cat="cat3" id="theButton2" src="https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/4039958/ama-orange.0.png" style="height:50px" />

    <input type="image" id="theButton3" src="https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/4039958/ama-orange.0.png" style="height:50px" />

    <input type="image" id="theButton4" src="https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/4039958/ama-orange.0.png" style="height:50px" />

    <input type="image" id="theButton5" src="https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/4039958/ama-orange.0.png" style="height:50px" />

    <input type="image" id="theButto6n" src="https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/4039958/ama-orange.0.png" style="height:50px" />

    <input type="image" id="theButton7" src="https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/4039958/ama-orange.0.png" style="height:50px" />

    <input type="image" id="theButton8" src="https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/4039958/ama-orange.0.png" style="height:50px" />

    <input type="image" id="theButton9" src="https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/4039958/ama-orange.0.png" style="height:50x" />

 
    <p class="the-text cat1">1</p>
    <p class="the-text cat2">2</p>
    <p class="the-text cat1">3</p>
    <p class="the-text cat2">4</p>
    <p class="the-text cat1 cat2 cat3">5</p>
    <p class="the-text cat3">6</p>
    <p class="the-text">7</p>
    <p class="the-text">8</p>
    <p class="the-text1">9</p>
    <p class="the-text">10</p>
    <p class="the-text">11</p>
    <p class="the-text1">12</p>
    <p class="the-text">13</p>
    <p class="the-text">14</p>
    <p class="the-text1">15</p>
    <p class="the-text">16</p>
    <p class="the-text">17</p>
    <p class="the-text1">18</p>
    <p class="the-text1">19</p>
    </html>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Sempervivum/0qces5sm/31/)

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/0qces5sm/32/ I'm assuming not but it's kind of unclear what you're trying to do. Why would clicking the 2nd icon only make box #2 have a color - shouldn't it color #2 and #4?

Comment: maybe better `toggleClass` ;)

Comment: So you hit the nail on the head. I still just need it to be able to remove the change in css if the button is click again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, I think you just have an extra line in there that you don't need. Try this:

```
<script>
  $("input[type=image]").on ("click", function() {
    var cat = $(this).attr("data-cat");
    $("p.the-text." + cat).toggleClass("colorized");
  })
</script>
```

This line:

```
$("p.the-text").removeClass("colorized");
```

is unhighlighting all the boxes and then you're immediately re-highlighting 2, 4, and 5 because they have the 'cat2' class.

Edit: Used toggleClass() instead of addClass() to make the row unhighlighted when clicking the button again.

Comment: I don't really know the rules, but I would imagine they'd want you to make a new question. Go ahead and make it and I'll check your profile for the new question. Also pretty please mark this one as correct for me ^__^

Comment: I literally just took out that one line. Your code was correct otherwise: https://jsfiddle.net/0qces5sm/34/

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.

Comment: ahhh. So when a css is changed and then you click anothe button that wants to change the css it resorts it back to its original state instead of staying orange like it's supposed to. Check out box 5 when you click the first two buttons.

Comment: So the problem with box 5 is that you're toggling it again. That will require some more sophisticated logic, such as "if($(box).hasClass('colorized')) { $(box).toggleClass() } or some such. Give it a shot, I'm sure you can figure this out.